# react how to add condition to map for get one result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Hey guys what i wanna do is i have two collection i want to compare them if return true display ***solved*** else display ***Available***

**My first collection** :

```
    (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0:
    creatorUserId : "62f0eb420f2464344f019ab3",
    examname: "test exam",
    _id: "62f287dcee776e0f64687406"
```

**My second collection** :

```
 (2) [{…}, {…}]
 0:
 examId: "62f287dcee776e0f64687406"
 userId: "62f0eb490f2464344f019ab6"
 _id: "62fa8e8bdca7970649800c45"
 examReview: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

okey now i want to compare like **First collection:** _id == **Second collection** examId

if this condition returns true that means some user(userId) solved that exam now i have to display them like if they solved test before state will be *"Solved"* if they did not *"Available"*

**My code**

```
 <Header>Status report</Header>
        <Table>
          <Tr>
            <Th>Exam Name</Th>
            <Th>Link</Th>
            <Th>Status</Th>
          </Tr>
          {examDatas.map((exam, index) => (
            <Tr key={index}>
              <Td>{exam.examname}</Td>
              <Td><Link to={`/quiz/${exam._id}`}><Button>Go to exam</Button></Link></Td>
              {userDatas.map((user) => (
                <Td>{exam._id == user.examId ? (<span>{"Solved"}</span>) : (<span>{"Available"}</span>)}</Td>
              ))}
            </Tr>
          ))}
        </Table>
```

**My client image** :

[Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4mdd.png)

As you guys see status part is overflowing how can i solve this problem

I am working on it for so long i am open to any advice thanks for attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that column, you can search for the id

```
<Header>Status report</Header>
<Table>
  <Tr>
    <Th>Exam Name</Th>
    <Th>Link</Th>
    <Th>Status</Th>
  </Tr>
  {examDatas.map((exam, index) => (
  <Tr key={index}>
      <Td>{exam.examname}</Td>
      <Td><Link to={`/quiz/${exam._id}`}><Button>Go to exam</Button></Link></Td>
      <Td>{userDatas.findIndex(u=> u.examId === exam._id) > -1 ? (<span>{"Solved"}</span>) : <span>{"Available"}</span>}</Td>  
  </Tr>
  ))}
</Table>
```